# Determing if URL should have a forward slash at the end in Java

Tags: java, url, relative-url

I am trying to do some web crawling and I came across an issue of when to add a slash or not. I know that some sites do have it at the end and some don't but entering the wrong one in the browser will just redirect you to the right one. Normalization would add the slash at the end but its going to cause a problem when trying to convert the relative URLs to absolute.

For example if a user selects an absolute URL `http://stack.com/more` but the actual (redirect) URL is `http://stack.com/more/` and a relative url is `index.html`

Then doing `URL newurl = new URL(url, relativeURL);`

yields `http://stack.com/index.html` (non existant page)

when it should actually be `http://stack.com/more/index.html`(real page)

Doese anyone know a good way to correctly append the slash at the end?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If a relative URL starts with a `/`, it's only relative to the root (the domain). So both

```
http://stack.com/more/ + /index.html
```

and

```
http://stack.com/more + /index.html
```

are correctly resolved to

```
http://stack.com/index.html
```

**not**

```
http://stack.com/more/index.html
```

In your example, it makes no difference whatsoever whether there's a `/` at the end of `more`.

The trick comes in when there's no leading slash on the relative URL, e.g. `index.html`. When resolving those, you're supposed to remove the last segment and replace it with the relative path. It would make a difference in that case, because

```
http://stack.com/more/ + index.html
```

resolves to

```
http://stack.com/more/index.html
```

but

```
http://stack.com/more + index.html
```

resolves to

```
http://stack.com/index.html
```

(`index.html` replaces `more`, because `more` is the final segment).

Comment: For my example the relative url was not suppose to have a / in the beginning, that was a typo sorry. Say you dont know if the url should have the / at the end. Is there a strategy to decide the correct url? In your case, `http://stack.com/more/index.html`

Comment: @Dan: `http://stack.com/more` + `index.html` is correctly `http://stack.com/index.html`, not `http://stack.com/more/index.html`. I suspect the only way to know how to combine them is to make sure you have the canonical form of the first one. If the site responds to `http://stack.com/more` by redirecting you to `http://stack.com/more/`, then you know adding `index.html` should be `http://stack.com/more/index.html`. If it directly responds to `http://stack.com/more`, then you know that adding `index.html` to that should be `http://stack.com/index.html`.